# Xpath selector in python Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Right now I am learning how to use Xpath to scrape websites in combination with python Scrapy. Right now I am stuck at the following:

I am looking at a dutch website http://www.ah.nl/producten/bakkerij/brood where I want to scrape the names of the products:
 [image]

So eventually I want a csv file with the names of the articles of all these breads. If I inspect elements, I get to see where these names are defined:

[image]

I need to find the right XPath to extract "AH Tijgerbrood bruin heel". So what I thought I should do in my spider is the following:

```
import scrapy
from stack.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ah"
    allowed_domains = ["ah.nl"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.ah.nl/producten/bakkerij/brood']
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="product__description small-7 medium-12"]'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('h1/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Now, if I crawl with this spider, I dont get any result. I have no clue what I am missing here.

Comment: It is highly likely that the content you are trying to scape is not actually available when you fetch the URL. It is probably populated using Javascript after the page is loaded.  Try fetching `http://www.ah.nl/producten/bakkerij/brood` with `curl` and examining the resulting document.

Comment: @larsks thats exactly what is happening

Comment: @heinst: yes, I know, I looked before posting that comment :).

Comment: @larsks Does this mean that there is no way to scrape the names of the articles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python has some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) for this task since all the elements are loaded in JavaScript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.ah.nl/producten/bakkerij/brood")
#put an arbitrarily large number, you can tone it down, this is to allow the webpage to load
driver.implicitly_wait(40) 
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[local-name()= "div" and @class="product__description small-7 medium-12"]//*[local-name()="h1"]')
for elem in elements:
    print elem.text
```

Answer (score 0):

`title = response.xpath('//div[@class="product__description small-7 medium-12"]./h1/text').extract()[0]`